# Why ICU lib is so big?

Tags: linux, debian, embedded

I'm trying to reduce the size of an embedded system. So I'm studying what I could remove.

One of the biggest file is :
 libicudata.so.52.1 which length is 23 Mo. This is a big part of my system.

- I'm using java and apache : are they using libicu ?
- Why this file is so big ?
- Is there any alternative library ?

Comment: Do you really need Java in an embedded system?

Comment: I don't choose everything...

Answer (score 6):

Both the JRE and Apache use `libicu`, *via* `libxml2`. You can see this on your system by asking `aptitude` why it needs a package:

```
aptitude why apache2 libicu52
aptitude why openjdk-7-jre libicu52
```

This will show the “main” dependency tree which pulls in `libicu52`, starting respectively from Apache and the JRE. You can add `-v` after `why` to list all the dependency trees linking the two packages.

The library is huge because it contains an enormous database of character set conversion tables and locale data. You can get some idea of the contents by exploring the [mapping tables](http://site.icu-project.org/charts/charset) on the ICU web site.

I don’t think there are any alternative libraries, at least none which you can drop in easily as replacements. If you want a smaller system, your best bet is to rebuild `libxml2` without the `libicu` dependency.

Comment: Thank you for the command "why". All I see is "suggestion" throw doc package and groff (who formats man pages). So libicu is clearly not needed !

Answer (score 0):

FYI: If you're worried about the size of that library but you have the 'aptitude' command/package installed, then you might consider removing it (and all of the dependencies as well).